# Combine two lists and one array to create a 3D data list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have the following three lists:

```
x = {i, j};
y = {a, b, c};
z = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

Where `z` is the data corresponding to the `x` and `y` coordinates, `z(x_i,y_j) = z_ij`. I need to create an array of the following form:

```
zz = {{i, a, 1}, {i, b, 2}, {i, c, 3}, {j, a, 4}, {j, b, 5}, {j, c, 6}}
```

**How can I do it efficiently in Mathematica 10.0?**

---

This was my attempt so far:

```
zz = Table[{x[[ii]], y[[jj]], z[[ii, jj]]}, {ii, 1, Length[x]}, {jj, 1, Length[y]}]~Flatten~1
```

My ultimate goal is to plot (`ListPlot3D[zz]`) or interpolate this data (`Interpolation[zz]`), and `x` and `y` may be non-uniformly sampled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying Bill's answer

```
x = {i, j};
y = {a, b, c};
z = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

MapThread[Append, {Flatten[Outer[List, x, y], 1], Flatten@z}]
```

> {{i, a, 1}, {i, b, 2}, {i, c, 3}, {j, a, 4}, {j, b, 5}, {j, c, 6}}

Also

```
Transpose@Append[Transpose@Tuples@{x, y}, Flatten@z]
```

> {{i, a, 1}, {i, b, 2}, {i, c, 3}, {j, a, 4}, {j, b, 5}, {j, c, 6}}

Comment: Great, the first method is almost twice faster than Bill's answer for large arrays. The second one is ten times faster :O

Comment: This might be even faster because it avoids transposes: `MapThread[Append, {Tuples@{x, y}, Flatten@z}]`

Comment: It isn't :) It is as fast as your first guess

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
x = {i, j}; y = {a, b, c}; z = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
zz=MapThread[Flatten[List[#1,#2]] &, {Flatten[Outer[List,x,y],1], Flatten[z]}]
```

which returns

```
{{i, a, 1}, {i, b, 2}, {i, c, 3}, {j, a, 4}, {j, b, 5}, {j, c, 6}}
```

It seems like there should be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: This approach takes almost the same time as mine for large lists :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Join @@ (Thread[{x[[#]], y, z[[#]]}, List] & /@ {1, 2})
```

> {{i, a, 1}, {i, b, 2}, {i, c, 3}, {j, a, 4}, {j, b, 5}, {j, c, 6}}